# Composer doesn't work on my user

Tags: php, windows, laravel, cmd, composer-php

I have a problem after installing "Composer" for Windows. I have installed it with the installer for windows and added the path.

But when I type: composer in CMD nothing shows up, Just an empty rule.

[image]

When I try to use the Composer in the user from my brother its work !

What is the Problem, and how can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: remove composer completely and go to Run Type AppData then go to Roaming and find the folder call Composer and delete it, then reinstall composer again

Comment: Can you clarify how you installed composer? Is your brother using the same computer?

Comment: Thanks  Supun for your help!